# Android Studio: Is there an efficient way to find constants needed to pass to the function?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

For example in this situation:

```
this.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

Here I know which constant to look for (as I know I want to hide the view). But many times I've come accross a situation where it is expecting an Int (from some constant defined god knows where) but I have no clue where to find the corresponding constants. It'd be great if the IDE showed me at least where to look for the constants or a list of these.
Usually I end up googling everywhere and it is really frustrating because in my opinion it's just there but unneccessarily hidden.
**Am I missing something?**

Comment: `progressBar.setVisiblility()` is the method just click on it and jump to the definition .

Comment: @ADM sometimes that does not get me much further. For example `getSharedPreferences(this.getString(R.string.sharedPreferences), MODE_PRIVATE)` 
No clue where to find the MODE_PRIVATE without consulting the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We understand your concern, that for every different functionality there is no suggestion provided by IDE automatically.
Also, there is no single place where all constants like View.VISIBLE are defined.
We have to type them/find them manually.

You can submit a request to IntelliJ Team (the Team who develops Android Studio IDE) to fix this functionality.

Please submit your request [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?_ga=2.85350425.1692713548.1612111174-750062662.1612111174)